# How should i drop multiple columns in redshift database?

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, ddl

Hello there i am trying to drop columns from my table specifically in **Amazon Redshift Database** i have tried "**Alter Table ABC drop column C1,drop column C2**" and "**Alter Table ABC drop column C1,C2)**" but it show error and didn't execute

Comment: ... post trail code and error... and moify question according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: FWIW, I came here because I ran into the same issue after trying the PostgreSQL-style syntax for dropping multiple columns, and I get the syntax error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","` followed by a caret pointing to the `,` following `drop column C1,`

Answer (score 9):

From [Redshift's ALTER TABLE documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html), you **cannot** drop several columns at once, cf:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
{
ADD table_constraint |
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ] |
OWNER TO new_owner |
RENAME TO new_name |
RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_name |
ADD [ COLUMN ] column_name column_type
[ DEFAULT default_expr ]
[ ENCODE encoding ]
[ NOT NULL | NULL ] |
DROP [ COLUMN ] column_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ] }

where table_constraint is:

[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
{ UNIQUE ( column_name [, ... ] )  |
PRIMARY KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) |
FOREIGN KEY (column_name [, ... ] )
REFERENCES  reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]}
```

Therefore, I would recommend you to proceed as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE ABC DROP COLUMN C1;
ALTER TABLE ABC DROP COLUMN C2;
```

Comment: This is correct, and also the case for `ADD COLUMN`, too